# Link blend multiple times

Tags: linked-data

I am solving this problem in all my animations. I need to use same linked group of objects multiple times (characters and vehicles). But it looks that Blender can link group only once and after Make Proxy my object is jumping between proxies.

My workaround is, copy Blend file to another position and link it as another file. Is there better solution?

Comment: I think this is a known limitation of the current system, not sure there any workaround other than what you already mentioned. I think it is planed to be improved for upcoming 2.8# series

Comment: Why Make Proxy and not link group directly? Linking a group more than once without Make Proxy works okay.

Comment: I need Make Proxy for animation on armature.

Comment: Is there any improvement you know of on this yet... I am running into the same problem needing to have lots of the same character in the same scenes... asked a question here...https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80522/multiple-character-instances-with-blenrig-workflow